# Does somebody need to be in the Chamber to control the Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* it is revealed that

> Ginny is being possessed by Tom Riddle and is the one opening the Chamber of Secrets.

The book seems relatively without holes in this regard.  However in the movie when Harry discovers Justin Flinch-Fletchley we see moments prior to this

> Ginny is studying in a room full of people.

This implies that the person opening the chamber of secrets couldn't have been in the chamber when the second attack occurs.  Is this just a goof in the movie or is there an alternate explanation for this?  Is the Basilisk acting on its own in the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potential explanations:

1. They messed up in the movie, and the timeline just doesn't fit.
2. Ginny had opened the Chamber earlier (while being possessed by the diary Riddle) and then gone to study with a group of students to avoid suspicion.
3. The diary Riddle was sufficiently powerful at that time that he didn't need Ginny to open the Chamber any more.

Comment: In my opinion, books should take precedence over movies. If a book makes something clear but it's hazy in the movie, go with the book.

Comment: @KatieR This is typically how I view things but it's still interesting taking the film versions on their own.  Not everybody that watches the movies will have read the books.